# JavaScript class methods and their properties. Trouble with code - how to pass arrays into properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, methods, properties

I've had trouble dealing with my exercise (I'm fairly new to this) and for some reason, I cannot transfer an array into my child class constructor using the parent's method + parameter. aaaannnd I probably have a whole bunch of other problems on my code, but I'll try debugging myself for now.

```
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name;
    this._level = level;              //['primary', 'middle', 'high'];
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  get level() {
    return this._level;
  }
  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents;
  }
  set numberOfStudents(newNumberOfStudents) {
    if (typeof newNumberOfStudents === number) {
      this._numberOfStudents = newNumberOfStudents
    } else {
      console.log(`The number of students must be numerical`);
      // might have to return something here
    }
  }

  quickFacts() {
    console.log(`${this.name} educates ${this.numberOfStudents} students, typically between the ages of ${this.level}.`);
  }

  static pickSubstituteTeacher(substituteTeachers) {
    let teacher = Math.floor(Math.random() * substituteTeachers.length);
    return substituteTeachers[teacher];
  }
}

class PrimarySchool extends School {
  constructor(name, numberOfStudents, pickupPolicy){
    super(name, 'primary', numberOfStudents);

    this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy;
  }
  get pickupPolicy() {
    return this._pickupPolicy;
  }
}

const lorraineHansbury = new PrimarySchool('Lorraine Hansbury', 514, 'Students must be picked up by a parent, guardian, or a family member over the age of 13.')

lorraineHansbury.quickFacts();

School.pickSubstituteTeacher(['Jamal Crawford', 'Lou Williams', 'J. R. Smith', 'James Harden', 'Jason Terry', 'Manu Ginobli']);
console.log(School.pickSubstituteTeacher());
```

I appreciate any input and also comments on what I did wrong here in terms of formatting the question itself.

Comment: **1.** `typeof newNumberOfStudents === number` should be `typeof newNumberOfStudents === "number"`.

Comment: **2.** You're calling `School.pickSubstituteTeacher()` without passing an array of teachers, thus `substituteTeachers` will be `undefined` and errors of the type `Can't access property <property> of undefined` will be thrown.

Comment: Check your console!

Comment: thank you Ibrahim! I guess thats why my .length isn't registering any input :)

Comment: You're welcome! Always check your console for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling `console.log(School.pickSubstituteTeacher());` there is no parameters passed so it will not work on this line `let teacher = Math.floor(Math.random() * substituteTeachers.length);` as `substituteTeachers` its undefined.

I have fixed that and its working let me know if you have any other issues

```js
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name;
    this._level = level;              //['primary', 'middle', 'high'];
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  get level() {
    return this._level;
  }
  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents;
  }
  set numberOfStudents(newNumberOfStudents) {
    if (typeof newNumberOfStudents === typeof Number) {
      this._numberOfStudents = newNumberOfStudents
    } else {
      console.log(`The number of students must be numerical`);
      // might have to return something here
    }
  }

  quickFacts() {
    console.log(`${this.name} educates ${this.numberOfStudents} students, typically between the ages of ${this.level}.`);
  }

  static pickSubstituteTeacher(substituteTeachers) {

   let teacher = Math.floor(Math.random() * substituteTeachers.length);
    return substituteTeachers[teacher];
  }
}

class PrimarySchool extends School {
  constructor(name, numberOfStudents, pickupPolicy){
    super(name, 'primary', numberOfStudents);

    this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy;
  }
  get pickupPolicy() {
    return this._pickupPolicy;
  }
}

const lorraineHansbury = new PrimarySchool('Lorraine Hansbury', 514, 'Students must be picked up by a parent, guardian, or a family member over the age of 13.')

lorraineHansbury.quickFacts();

console.log(School.pickSubstituteTeacher(['Jamal Crawford', 'Lou Williams', 'J. R. Smith', 'James Harden', 'Jason Terry', 'Manu Ginobli']));
//console.log(School.pickSubstituteTeacher());
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It actually helped a lot. 
What if I wanted to pass an array into class PrimarySchool's pickup policy? would I just insert it when I define the parameters for the class in the new PrimarySchool?